# Looking for a short story where there are murders taking place with magic

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic

I remember that the story had to do with murders happening with magic. One was a puzzle maker another was a doll maker. Investigator is a woman and gets a lead where she needs to find a specific toy maker. Magic makes the streets appear and disappear so you are not sure where you are going. 
Toy maker is able to give leads to the young lady and I remember there was also this young child who has horrible nightmares and investigator takes the little girl to the toy maker who then puts her in a dream trance, and introduces a toy camel in the trance which helps the little girl with her dreams.

Investigator also has magic, but limited. Amount of magic is given by the amount of time your mother is in labor. Her mother had a short labor.

Toy maker turns out to be death. Made by the group that has been murdered. They kept his mother in labor with magic for more than 3 days I think. A side effect is that he is actually hairless and brow less, though he does wear a black haired wig.

Investigator falls in love with 'death' and kisses him at the end, though his lips are ice cold, as tears run softly from her eyes.

Have been looking for this story for AGES! It was in a thick short story compilation and it was in the early 90's, I think.  I thought it had the word Green in it for some reason.

Help!

Answer (score 11):

This is the *Liavek: City of Luck* series

> Specifically: *Casting Fortune* By John M. Ford and the short story "Green is the Color"
>
> In "Green is the Color," the owner of the toy shop's mother was magically kept in labor for about a year, making his "luck time" on all the time. He would be compelled to assassinate people and appear glowing green to them as he killed them.

Answer lifted from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40465/1980s-book-about-a-man-who-glows-green-and-can-use-magic-based-upon-how-long-hi)